# Find matching numbers

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to write a PLSQL query that will in two separate columns print random integers.
It will print 1000 numbers total (random 1 - 50 in each row).
What I need to figure out is how I after this has been done, replace the second column with either "yes" or "no" if it matches the first column
Such as:

```
Col A    Col B
 10      NO(42)
 32      NO(12)
 25      YES(25)
```

And so on.
This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE table
      
   (random_num INTEGER NOT NULL,
    match INTEGER NOT NULL);

Declare

CURSOR cur_ IS 
(Select 

random_num,
match 
from table);

Begin 
  
FOR rec_ IN 1..1000 
    
  LOOP    
 
 INSERT INTO "table" (random_num,match) VALUES (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50),DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,50));
   
  END LOOP;
  
  END;
```

Now this works as I get two 1000 rows of each column with random numbers, but I need to implement this select:

```
SELECT random_num, CASE WHEN random_num = match THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END as match
FROM table
```

Into the loop so. Any takers on how I can do?

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong in what you said. You can't put `yes` (string) into an `INTEGER` datatype column.

This makes more sense:

Sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test
  2  (
  3     random_num_1   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  4     random_num_2   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  5     match          VARCHAR2 (3) NOT NULL
  6  );

Table created.
```

Procedure: use local variables to store random numbers; then it is easy to compare them.

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     val1  NUMBER;
  3     val2  NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5     FOR i IN 1 .. 10 --> change it to 1000
  6     LOOP
  7        val1 := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 50);
  8        val2 := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 50);
  9
 10        INSERT INTO test (random_num_1, random_num_2, match)
 11                VALUES (val1,
 12                        val2,
 13                        CASE WHEN val1 = val2 THEN 'yes' ELSE 'no' END);
 14     END LOOP;
 15  END;
 16  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

RANDOM_NUM_1 RANDOM_NUM_2 MAT
------------ ------------ ---
          45           31 no
          40           48 no
          43           27 no
          49           41 no
           6           38 no
           5           18 no
          18           35 no
          15           34 no
          11           19 no
          37           39 no

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to produce random *integers* from *1 to 50* that are equaly distributed, you must be carefull.

`[DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 50)][1]` returns a *decimal* number greater than or *equal* than 1 and *less* than 50.

example

```
select DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (1, 50) col from dual;
       COL
----------
30,4901593
```

You `cast` the result in `INTEGER` type that performs *rounding*, so you will see all numbers, but the 1 and 50 will appear only *half* frequenty as other numbers.

So a better way to get random integers  `1 .. 50`  is `1 + trunc(50*DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE)`

`VALUE` without parameters returns `[0,1)`

Also typically if you do not need to use `PL/SQL` do not use it

```
create table tab1 as
select 1 + trunc(50*DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) col1, 1 + trunc(50*DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE) col2
from dual connect by level <= 10 /* increase as much rows are needed */
```

and add the `MATCH`  column as virtual

```
alter table tab1 
add (match varchar2(3) generated always as (
  case when col1 = col2 then 'YES' else 'NO' end ) virtual);

      COL1       COL2 MAT
---------- ---------- ---
        33          6 NO 
        26         28 NO 
        35         22 NO 
        30         27 NO 
        17         45 NO 
        31          4 NO 
        11         21 NO 
         2         48 NO 
        35         25 NO 
        39         15 NO
```